# Capture image in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webcam

I want to capture image using webcam in asp.net web application. I have tried google a lot, and i could come up with only one solution i.e. using flash. Is there any other way to use webcam in web application. 
i tried avicap32.dll, however i think it can only be used with windows forms and not in web application.

Please help me with alternative solutions..

P.S. I forgot to inform that this should work on ie

Comment: This might be a good starting point; http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/chapter13.html

Comment: The only way you are going to be able to reliably use a webcam in a web application is either with Flash or Silverlight. As of Silverlight 4, it has [native support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282(v=vs.95).aspx) for capturing webcam videos and/or images. HTML5 has support for this too, however, it is limited to specific browsers. Check out [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: You could also use a 3rd party webcam activeX to meet your needs. Check out this article and see if it helps:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529721/Take-a-Photo-from-a-Desktop-Webcam-and-Upload-in-a